# XAMPP is currently only availably as 32 bit application. Please use a 32 bit compatibility library for your system

Tags: 12.04, xampp

When I try to install XAMPP, I get

```
XAMPP is currently only availably as 32 bit application.  Please use a 32 bit compatibility library for your system
```

How do I fix this error?

Comment: Somehow the inline image is broken - take a look at the other question (in edit mode) where I fixed it.

Comment: what is your os type 32 bit or 64 bit and how do you want to install xampp

Answer (score 1):

For solving that type of error please install lib32 using following command:

```
sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6
```

And then try starting/installing Xampp again.

**Source:** [XAMPP is currently only availably as 32 bit application. Please use a 32 bit compatibility library for your system – Shrinath's Blog](https://shrinathsuccess.wordpress.com/tag/xampp-is-currently-only-availably-as-32-bit-application-please-use-a-32-bit-compatibility-library-for-your-system/)